# Volatile weirdness

Tags: c#, multithreading

I think most people are aware of the following issue which happens when building in Release mode (code taken from [Threading in C#](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx)):

```
static void Main()
{
  bool complete = false; 

  var t = new Thread (() =>
  {
    bool toggle = false;
    while (!complete) toggle = !toggle;
  });

  t.Start();
  Thread.Sleep (1000);

  complete = true;
  t.Join();        // Blocks indefinitely
}
```

due to compiler optimizations caching the value of `complete` and thus preventing the child thread from ever seeing the updated value.

However, changing the above code a bit:

```
class Wrapper
{
    public bool Complete { get; set; }
}

class Test
{
    Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();

    static void Main()
    {
        var test = new Test();
        var t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            bool toggle = false;
            while (!test.wrapper.Complete) toggle = !toggle;
        });

        t.Start();
        Thread.Sleep(1000);

        test.wrapper.Complete = true;
        t.Join();        // Blocks indefinitely
    }
}
```

makes the problem go away (i.e. the child thread is able to exit after 1 second) without the use of `volatile`, memory fences, or any other mechanism that introduces an implicit fence.

How does the added encapsulation of the completion flag influence its visibility between threads?

Comment: Your code is not guaranteed to work, but it's also not guaranteed to fail. You shouldn't rely on compiler optimizations for correctness (or incorrectness in this case).

Comment: @svick: I'm not actually. It was just something I noticed accidentally.

Comment: possible duplicate of [A reproducable example of volatile usage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164466/a-reproducable-example-of-volatile-usage)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have answer in your question:

> due to *compiler optimizations* caching the value of complete and thus preventing the child thread from ever seeing the updated value.

Compiler/JIT optimizations are performed whenever it makes sense/deemed safe and reasonable to implement. So you found case when optimization is not performed the way you expect to happen - maybe there is a good reason (someone detected this usage pattern and block optimization) or it just happen not to be optimized (most likely).

Comment: The key point is that this is undefined behavior.  The compiler team could decide tomorrow to optimize the properties in the same way as the first example, or they could not optimize the first (or do so differently) such that it doesn't halt.

Comment: I agree with your point and most likely this is the case. I'm just trying to find out if there is a pattern that I can spot when determining whether code like this will fail or not.

Answer (score 0):

The first case is a simple alias propagation on a local variable. Compilers do that quite aggressively ([http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29)) The second case, even if it looks the same due to syntactic resemblance of properties to member variables, has method calls (getter/setter) and cannot be simply simplified.

Comment: in first case, it is not a simple setting of value.. runtime cannot just "ignore" something like that

Comment: don't get what you mean by "is not a simple setting of value". Alias propagation is a compiler technique to simplify or substitute variables http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_(computing)