# How fields of reference type can be nonvolatile?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, volatile

Here is what [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) says about `volatile`:

> The volatile keyword indicates that a field might be modified by
>   multiple threads that are executing at the same time. Fields that are
>   declared volatile are not subject to compiler optimizations that
>   assume access by a single thread. This ensures that **the most
>   up-to-date value is present in the field at all times**.
>
> The volatile keyword can be applied to fields of these types:
>   Reference types.

This state implies that fields of reference type are not volatile by default.
I think it's ok to treat reference-type field as a field of value type containing the address of the object. Then it becomes similar to `int` type. Joe Albahari [gives some examples](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part4.aspx#_Memory_Barriers_and_Volatility).

But!... Unlike usual value types GC moves objects into memory when it compacts the heap and changes the references accordingly. Hence 'the most up-to-date value' must always be there. And if so how does the concept of volatility apply to reference types?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> This state implies that fields of reference type are not volatile by
>   default.

Sure. No field is treated as `volatile` by default because `volatile` comes together with the possibility of a sizable performance cost.

> I think it's ok to treat reference-type field as a field of value type
>   containing the address of the object. Then it becomes similar to int
>   type.

Assume this can be done without problems. So what? Fields of scalar types such as `int` or `bool` are also not treated as volatile by default.

> Unlike usual value types GC moves objects into memory when it compacts
>   the heap and changes the references accordingly. Hence 'the most
>   up-to-date value' must always be there. And if so how does the concept
>   of volatility apply to reference types?

You are slightly confused about the utility of `volatile`. The problem it is meant to address is not only that (A) the most up to date value *is not there* (although `volatile` semantics do guarantee that any writes to the value will be observable by any reads that follow them in an abstract timeline¹).

Apart from that, it is also meant to address the situation (B) where the compiler assumes that *the code it generates is the only party modifying that value* (or the value is not being modified at all), which means that it will not *choose* to read the value from the field and instead use a "cached copy" it already has at hand. If the value *is* being modified by a third party at the same time this is obviously going to result in the program using the wrong data for its calculations.

For more information you can refer to this excellent [analysis](http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained/) by Igor Ostrovsky, wherein (A) is referred to as "processor optimizations" and (B) as "compiler optimizations".

---

¹ Please note that this is not a rigorous definition but rather just a crude approximation.

Comment: 'compiler assumes that it is the only party modifying that value' I think this is confusing. Modifying value is run time, compiler works at compile time. Compiler can't modify these values because the program has not run yet. I suggest rewording.

Comment: @zespri: The compiler can "prove" that the value is not being modified when e.g. there are no writes to it anywhere in the code. It doesn't need to run the program to do this. Do you still feel that the wording is off?

Comment: I'd suggest something along the lines of "...the compiler assumes that the generated code is the only party modifying that value (or the value is not being modified at all), which means that it will not choose to generate code to read the value..." but may be it's just me. To be clear: I understand what you are saying, but I see an ambiguity that I'm trying to point out.

Comment: @zespri: That sounds reasonable, I edited to match. Thanks for the feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Volatile IS useful for reference fields.

Consider this program:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Flag
    {
        public volatile bool Value;
    }

    sealed class Program
    {
        private void run()
        {
            flag.Value = true;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(resetFlagAfter1s);
            int x = 0;

            while (flag.Value)
                ++x;

            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }

        private void resetFlagAfter1s()
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            flag = new Flag();
            flag.Value = false;
        }

        private Flag flag = new Flag();

        private static void Main()
        {
            new Program().run();
        }
    }
}
```

If you run a RELEASE (not debug) build of this, it will never terminate (Visual Studio 2013, .Net 4.5x)

If you change the declaration of `flag` to:

```
private volatile Flag flag = new Flag();
```

Then the release build WILL terminate. This proves that `volatile` can be significant for a reference field.

Comment: @voroninp Have you used Release mode when compiling it?

Comment: @Dirk Yes. Release-AnyCPU, VS2013, Win7, Intel Core i7, M620 2.67GHz x64

Comment: @voroninp I'm sorry, you are right. I was testing a slightly modified version of the code in LINQpad. If you remove the volatile from the boolean field in the Flag class it won't terminate. If you think that's because it's a value type simply change it to object and test for null.

Comment: @Dirk Alas..still terminates when it is object. And even if bool. That is strange.

Comment: @voroninp This is the test code I use in LINQpad: `class Test { public volatile object condition = null; } static void Main() { var test = new Test(); new Thread(() => { test.condition = new object();}).Start(); while (test.condition == null) {} }`. I hope you can reproduce it but that's all I can do, sorry.

Comment: @voroninp It definitely doesn't terminate without the volatile if you run it in release mode. Note that if you run it under the debugger, even a release build will be run in non-release build. So you must either run it from the command line or via "Debug|Start Without Debugging" (which is Ctrl-F5 by default. If you're pressing F5, you're doing it wrong!)

Comment: @MatthewWatson Well, if I remove volatile from Value - it doesn't terminate. And it terminates again if I add volatile to the flag field. But your intial code still terminates. That's confusing.

Comment: @voroninp It may be to do with different .Net versions. I tried this on .Net 4.51 with Windows 7 and Windows 8.1 and it works as I described on both those platforms.

Comment: What does GC do then to correctly substitute references with new values after compacting the heap?

Comment: I don't invent, just trying to understand.

Comment: @voroninp The GC is too complex to explain about in comments here. I can direct you to the book "CLR via C#, 4th Edition" which has an excellent chapter on the GC.

Comment: @voroninp The GC mechanism (well one of them, it's complicated) involves parking all threads which involves synchronization which again involves memory barriers.

Answer (score 1):

I think that Jon answered this question.

I would add that the "only" thing that volatile keyword does is to add an hidden attribute on a field, and to alter the way code is compiled (to IL).

For instance:

```
    static int x = 0;
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        if (x == 0)
            x++;
    }
```

is compiled to

```
L_0000: ldsfld int32 Tests.Program::x
L_0005: brtrue.s L_0013
L_0007: ldsfld int32 Tests.Program::x
L_000c: ldc.i4.1 
L_000d: add 
L_000e: stsfld int32 Tests.Program::x
L_0013: ret
```

If you take a look at this part:

```
ldsfld x
brtrue.s L_0013
ldsfld x
```

(literally "load a field, if zero, jump. else, load it again")

The first two will translate to something like this in "pseudo asembler"

- load value of x in a register (mov)
- if zero, jump elsewhere (jz)

For the third, I guess that the CLR will be tempted to say "hey, I already know that my register contains the value of x, why not skipping the third instruction ?"

... "volatile" keyword prevents this kind of optimizations.

change x definition to `static volatile int x=0`, and you get:

```
L_0000: volatile. 
L_0002: ldsfld int32 modreq([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile) Tests.Program::x
L_0007: brtrue.s L_0019
L_0009: volatile. 
L_000b: ldsfld int32 modreq([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile) Tests.Program::x
L_0010: ldc.i4.1 
L_0011: add 
L_0012: volatile. 
L_0014: stsfld int32 modreq([mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IsVolatile) Tests.Program::x
L_0019: ret
```

(same thing with reference fields)

See [Opcodes.Volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.volatile%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) :

> Specifies that an address currently atop the evaluation stack might be volatile, and the results of reading that location cannot be cached or that multiple stores to that location cannot be suppressed.

[I recomand you to read Hans Passant excelent answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164466/a-reproducable-example-of-volatile-usage)